# jquery validation messages using ids rather than name for a rails form with same name

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

Hi i am having rails form consisting of email, name etc; and field name with questions comes from yml file. For the 3 sets of questions the user has to fill 3 answers respectively.

form:

> ```
>     <% @list = YAML::load(File.open("#{Rails.root}/config/questions.yml"))%>
>     <% ans_iter= 0 %>
>     <% @list.keys.each do |set| %>
>     <% ans_iter += 1 %>
>     <%= select_tag 'questions[]',options_for_select(@list[set]) %>
>     <%= text_field_tag "answers[]", nil, :class => 'required', :id => "ans_#{ans_iter}"%>
>     <% end %>
> ```

Initially there are no iteration attributes(ans_iter in the above form), at that time when i do Inspect element, i used to get ids of each answer text box as **answers_** and class name as **answers[]**. But later after adding of iterators i am getting ids as ans_1, ans_2, ans_3 respectively.

When i write validator messages as:

> function validatePage(){
>
> ```
> validator = $('#new_user').validate({
>     rules: {  user_first_name:{ required:true},
>         user_email: { required:true},
>         ans_1: {required:true},
>         ans_2: {required:true},
>         ans_3: {required:true} },
>     messages: {
>         user_first_name:{ required: "Please enter First Name"},
>         user_email:   { required: "Please enter Email"},
>         ans_1: {required: "Please fill the answer"},
>         ans_2: {required: "Please fill the answer"},
>         ans_3: {required: "Please fill the answer"} }
> }); }
> ```

For the above js, only 1st answer text box validation is working, remaining 2 answer tex boxes are not working. I think my validator is working with names rather than ids. Is there a way to run my validations with ids?

Answer (score 1):

Why not do

...

```
'answers[]': {required:true}
```

...

```
'answers[]': {required: "Please fill the answer"}
```

Comment: You can only validate using name, not id when using this plugin.  So if you are trying to have multiple text fields with the same `name` that will not work.  Perhaps give the answer fields names like `ans_1`, `ans_2`, etc. and then it will work...